# Angular ng-click: $scope variable change followed by promise prevents scope from updating

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-promise

I have a `ng-click` function that should change the button text and run an asynchronous function.

**template**

```
<button ng-click="connect()">{{buttonTextConnect}}</button>
```

**connect()**

```
$scope.connect = function() {
    console.log('Try connecting');
    $scope.buttonTextConnect = 'Connecting...';

    thermProbe.connect().then(
        function() {
            $scope.connected = true;
        },
        function() {
            $scope.connected = false;
        }
      );
}
```

The `console.log` is immediately displayed. The `$scope.buttonTextConnect` does not update the text within the button however.

`thermProbe.connect()` is an Angular promise.

If I comment out the async call `thermProbe.connect()` the button text is updated as expected.

Here is a working [Ionic Play demo](http://play.ionic.io/app/04ea42abed97), which works as expected. The button text changes when clicked and the promise resolves later.

Why does the asynchronous call prevent the `$scope` change from updating in the template?

Comment: What does `thermProbe.connect()` do?

Comment: Connects to a Bluetooth device via a Cordova plugin. `thermProbe.connect()` returns a promise.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody you may need to apply digest cycle by doing `$scope.$apply()` as it seems outside angular context

Comment: Are you saying I should run `$scope.$apply()` before the async call? It seems as though the `connect()` function is waiting to finish (with the resolve from the promise) before running `$digest`.

Comment: Does it return an Angular promise? If not, then what @PankajParkar wrote is the correct solution. Unless this is your code, which in that case you should be using the $q service.

Comment: `thermProbe.connect()` returns an Angular promise.

Comment: I dug a little deeper into the Cordova plugin. A method within the plugin isn't running asynchronously, which is causing the issue.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody does it fixed now?